# CSV Import Powershell - AD

Tags: powershell, csv, import

Hi I am running the below code to update user information in AD

```
import-module activedirectory

$Users=Import-CSV C:\UserFeed.csv 

foreach($_ in $Users)
{

if ($_."FAX" -ne $null){
$fax = $_."FAX"
}
else {
$fax = $null
}

if ($_."MOBILETELEPHONE" -ne $null){
$mobile = $_."MOBILETELEPHONE"
}
else {
$mobile = $null
}

if ($_."COUNTRY" -ne $null){
$country = $_."COUNTRY"
}
else {
$country = $null
}

 $Mgr = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$($_."REPORTSTOEMAIL")'" |              
Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

Get-ADUser -filter "EmailAddress -like '$($_.EMAILPRIMARY)'" | 
Set-ADUser -Replace @{physicalDeliveryOfficeName=($_."ACTUALOFFICE");Title=             
($_."PERSONALJOBTITLE");department=($_."DeptName");company=  
($_."COMPANYNAME");facsimileTelephoneNumber="$fax";StreetAddress=  
($_."STREET");l=($_."TOWNCITY");postalCode=($_."POSTZIPCODE");Co=$country;C=
($_."COUNTRY2");CountryCode=($_."COUNTRY3");givenName=($_."KNOWNAS");sn=
($_."LASTNAME");telephoneNumber=($_."WORKTELEPHONE");mobile="$mobile
";manager="$Mgr"}
}
```

The issue is in the CSV where an user say does not have fax number and the field is blank instead of putting nothing in fax it puts space character.  How do I get it to not set anything for that field.

Example please see image http://s22.postimg.org/nsf66ngc1/mobile.jpg

Here is what CSV looks like

TITLE,KNOWNAS,LASTNAME,INITIALS,DIVISION,DEPARTMENTCODE,COMPANYREFNO,WORKTELEPHO‌​NE,MOBILETELEPHONE,WORKPHONESHORTCODE,EMAILPRIMARY,FAX,STREET,TOWNCITY,POSTZIPCOD‌​E,COUNTRY,COMPANYNAME,REPORTSTOEMAIL,ACTUALOFFICE,DeptName,Office,COUNTRY2,COUNTR‌​Y3 Mr,Peter,Smith,P,Executive,IT,PL,+44 (0) 1234 567 890,,,user1@testdomain.co.uk,+44 (0) 1234 567 890,Road,London,QWER,United Kingdom,COMPANY,j.smith,OfficeName,Computers,City,GB,826

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried the code amendment but I still get the weird character in AD when the field should just be empty in AD. The issue seems to be with the $fax = $null. For null why is it putting that weird character –

Comment: I strongly recommend against `foreach($_ in $Users)` syntax.  `$_` is a reserved variable.  If you want to use it, I recommend using to ForEach-Object cmdlet (`$Users | ForEach-Object {[...]}`) instead of the foreach statement.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to test a string in this case would be **[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace()**

Try this:

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_."FAX"){
    $fax = $null
} else {
    $fax = $_."FAX" 
}
```

Comment: I tried the code amendment but I still get the weird character in AD when the field should just be empty in AD.   The issue seems to be with the $fax = $null.  For null why is it putting that weird character

Comment: OK, try $Fax ="" instead.

Comment: i tried with "" and still same thing it gives that funny character

Comment: Have you checked that the "FAX" field is actually a string? And not something silly like an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_."FAX" -ne $null -and $_."FAX" -ne " "){
$fax = $_."FAX"
}
else {
$fax = $null
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul.  I updated the code for mobile, fax and country as to what you suggested but still not working.  Please see link to screenshot of what appears in AD http://s22.postimg.org/nsf66ngc1/mobile.jpg As you can see the mobile field has that funny character and if you copy and paste it into notepad that character it is space

Comment: Here is what CSV looks like TITLE,KNOWNAS,LASTNAME,INITIALS,DIVISION,DEPARTMENTCODE,COMPANYREFNO,WORKTELEPHONE,MOBILETELEPHONE,WORKPHONESHORTCODE,EMAILPRIMARY,FAX,STREET,TOWNCITY,POSTZIPCODE,COUNTRY,COMPANYNAME,REPORTSTOEMAIL,ACTUALOFFICE,DeptName,Office,COUNTRY2,COUNTRY3
Mr,Peter,Smith,P,Executive,IT,PL,+44 (0) 1234 567 890,,,user1@testdomain.co.uk,+44 (0) 1234 567 890,Road,London,QWER,United Kingdom,COMPANY,j.smith,OfficeName,Computers,City,GB,826

Comment: @user3770745 Please add that to your question. No one can read that in comments